# smoothing line with categorical variable with ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2, smoothing

I have a huge data sets and this is a sample.

```
data.frame(basket_size_group = c("[0,2]", "[0,2]", "(2,4]", "(2,4]", "(4,6]"),
       channel = c("offline", "online/mobile", "offline", "online/mobile", "offline"), 
       pct_trips = c(0.004, 0.038, 0.0028, 0.0082, 0.0037))
```

By using a `ggplot2`, I would like to plot smoothing line with the data. Xaxis is the `basket_size_group`, yaxis is `pct_trips`, `channel` is a group in `ggplot2` . The problem is that `basket_size_group` is a categorical variable. How to create smoothing lines by `channel` with `ggplot2`?

Comment: do you really want smoothing lines or connected points linked together?

Comment: Hope to have a smoothing line. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use a loess smooth you will need some more data. As it sits `stat_smooth()` will fail with the error:

```
Computation failed in `stat_smooth()`:
NA/NaN/Inf in foreign function call (arg 5)
```

Unless you specify `method = "lm"`.

You also have to be explicit with the `stat_smooth()` layer and define that `group = channel`. You could do that in the top layer too, but without it `stat_smooth` will try to use `x` and `color` to do its group summarizing.

```
# factor it to plot in order
dat$basket_size_group <- factor(dat$basket_size_group, levels = c("[0,2]", "(2,4]", "(4,6]"))

ggplot(dat, aes(basket_size_group, pct_trips, color = channel)) +
    geom_point() +
    stat_smooth(aes(group = channel), method = "lm")
```

[image]

Comment: My data set is quite large. When I did it I got this message. "Error: Aesthetics must be either length 1 or the same as the data (438549): x, y, colour" Do you have any idea?

Comment: did you run the `factor(...)` part, that might have messed up your data, look at `dat$basket_size_group` perhaps?